# Bath Tub replacement

Tags: bathtub

We're in the process of looking at getting a cracked fiberglass tub/shower replaced.  We had one contractor come out that recommended using an acrylic AKERbyMAAX tub.

I'm ok with the acrylic tub, but I've never heard of AKER.  I just want to know if this is a reasonably reputable brand and not something junky.  I'm not looking for a review so much as just some confirmation that there's no reason this brand should be a problem.

Specifically we're looking ACTS-3P in case that helps at all.

To add some additional clarity, we have reasonable budget, and I just want to make sure whatever we do, doesn't need to be re-done in the next decade (or longer).  Our current tub is only 5 years old and is cracked in the floor (its fiberglass).  I don't want something like this to happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard of the brand either. In general, cracked plastic (fiberglass, acrylic, whatever) tubs are a poor installation which ignored the key "secret" (not - it's usually right there in the instructions, being ignored) of bedding the tub in plaster, so that there is no flex on the bottom of it.

On the other hand, if you can get the heavy things moved into place, cast iron is darn near permanent.

Comment: I would love to do a cast iron, or steel tub, but I would like to avoid using tile on the walls.  Mostly a concern around cleaning + cost.